# I create a extension for VSCode and I would like to know, what event is fired when user changes tabs on VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

When the user clicks on tabs what events are dispatched in the VSCode extension api?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming by "tabs" you're referring to text editor windows, the `window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` event is probably what you're looking for. From the linked documentation:

> ##### onDidChangeActiveTextEditor: [Event](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Event)<[TextEditor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor) | undefined>
>
> An [Event](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Event) which fires when the [active editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.activeTextEditor) has changed. Note that the event also fires when the active editor changes to `undefined`.